# Possible integer roots of polynomial with real coefficents

Tags: polynomials, roots, estimation

If $p\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$, then the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) gives us possible integer roots of $p$. If $p\in\mathbb{R}[X]$, the theorem cannot be applied. Nevertheless, triangular inequality gives us lower and upper bound for *all* roots. If we define

$$p(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots a_1 x + a_0\text{,}$$
we notice that $$|p(x)|\,\geq\, |a_n||x^n| - \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} |a_i||x^i|\;\geq\, |a_n||x^n| - \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} A|x^i|\text{,} $$
where $A = \max_{0\leq i\leq n-1} |a_i|$. If $|x|>1$, it follows that
$$|a_n||x^n|> An|x|^{n-1}\Rightarrow |p(x)| > 0\text{.}$$
Define $B = \max \{1, An/a_n\}$. Then
$$|x|> B \Rightarrow p(x)\neq 0\text{.}$$

Thus, we obtain a finite number of possible integer roots.

> Are there any considerably better estimates for the region where integer roots might lie?

Comment: It is well known that a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots, even when we count complex ones and repetitions. Why this hard way  to prove finitely many integer roots?

Comment: @PVanchinathan Maybe, I was unclear. I have edited the question.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_.28complex.29_polynomial_roots, for instance, using quantities from the question, $B=1+A/|a_n|$ might be smaller if $A$ is large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in general there aren't any.